# How to pass Nextjs Component with custom properties as Children

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

To add a property `Auth` to my components. I have created an interface

```js
interface AuthAppProps extends Omit<AppProps, "Component"> {
  Component: AppProps["Component"] & { Auth: boolean };
}
```

So that I can perform

```js
const App: React.FC<AuthAppProps> = (props) =>{
  const {
    Component,
    pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },
  } = props;
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      {Component.Auth ? (
        <AuthGuard>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </AuthGuard>
      ) : (
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      )}
    </SessionProvider>
  );
}
```

I want to move this checking logic to another component which is

```js
const AuthProvider: React.FC<AuthProviderProps> = (
  props: AuthProviderProps
) => {
  const { children: Component } = props;

  if (Component.Auth) {
    return <AuthGuard>{Component}</AuthGuard>;
  } else {
    return <>{Component}</>;
  }
};
```

So that I can do

```js
 <SessionProvider session={session}>
      <AuthProvider>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </AuthProvider>
    </SessionProvider>
```

But since `<Component {...pageProps} />` is only passed as react Element not as my custom type. It gives me an error that

`Type 'Element' is not assignable to type '(NextComponentType<NextPageContext, any, {}> & { Auth: boolean; }) & ReactNode'`

How can I access Auth for my component when pass as children? is it possible?

### Update

```js
interface AuthProviderProps{
    children: AuthAppProps
}
```